# Как добавлять картинку при наведении курсора на кнопку?

Tags: css, css3, hover

Для сайта нужно чтобы при наведении на кнопку накладывалась на нее картинка, как в скрине. Решил я сделать это таким образом - наложить на кнопку картинку и скрыть, при наведении - она появляется. Но что-то пошло не так.

```
.man img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.man img:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Пробовал к картинке класс давать и те же действия проводить, но тот же результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте :before и :after

Comment: example - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/tw1xrnsq/

Answer (score 3):

```
.man img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.man:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```

в вашем случае вы `:hover` вешали на картинку, которую не видно. соответственно на нее нельзя навести манипулятор ввода типа мышь

Comment: действительно, а если картинку в div поместить и провести те же манипуляции?

Comment: нет, с div тоже не выходит..